# ¿Cual es la mejor estrategia para formular una consulta SQL con multiples WHERE?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, optimización

Soy bastante novato en SQL y todo el tema de optimización de consultas aún me queda grande.

Tengo una tabla con unos algunos millones de registros con los siguientes campos:

```
Referencia  Año Direccion   Provincia   Latitud Longitud    Superficie
```

Y quiero ejecutar una consulta filtrando por los campos:

- Año
- Latitud
- Longitud
- Superficie

Me imagino que un simple SELECT * FROM encadenando una serie de condiciones WHERE no debe ser la forma óptima de ejecutar la consulta así que me pregunto cual sería la estrategia a seguir.

No sé si tal vez lo ideal sería ejecutar una consulta previa sobre el campo Provincia y ejecutar la subconsulta a partir del resultado o qué camino seguir.

Añadir que la base de datos la voy a crear y gestionar yo, de modo que puedo añadir cuantas tablas auxiliares me apetezca sin restricciones.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

EDITO: La base de datos es, de momento, extremadamente sencilla (solo consta de una tabla) y aún no he hecho pruebas sobre el rendimiento ya que no dispongo de los datos completos, por el momento. Es posible, como sugerís, que simplemente en una única instrucción con varios WHERE + AND funcione suficientemente bien.

Dejo un ejemplo de cómo es, por ahora, la tabla (seguramente en el futuro tendré que añadir más campos).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Catastro" (
    "Referencia"    TEXT,
    "Year"  INTEGER,
    "Direccion" TEXT,
    "Provincia" TEXT,
    "Latitud"   REAL,
    "Longitud"  REAL,
    "Superficie"    REAL
);
INSERT INTO "Catastro" VALUES ('0913904VK4801D0001TI ',1965,'CL GRAN 
VIA','Madrid',40.477869,-3.697409,156.0);
INSERT INTO "Catastro" VALUES ('3208015VK4830G0001AU',1975,'CL SERRANO 
GALVACHE 20
28033 MADRID (MADRID)','Madrid',40.46845291,-3.67382251,140.0);
INSERT INTO "Catastro" VALUES ('1298602VK4719G0001RO',1960,'CL BRAVO MURILLO 
357
28020 MADRID (MADRID)','Madrid',40.45273691,-3.70339183,110.0);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Al contrario, cuando más afines en una consulta de selección, menos registros tendrás que llevar de disco a memoria. Utiliza WHERE y concatena con todos los AND que necesites. Lo de optimizar consultas viene más adelante. Envíanos la estructura de la base de datos en SQL con algún registro de muestra, dinos qué quieres obtener y cómo has intentado obtenerlo y ya te decimos si puedes optimizar algo. Ah, y mírate https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve para que podamos contestarte más rápido

Comment: El problema es que cuando se habla de *optimización* es bases de datos no puedes pensar solamente en la consulta (pensando en cuestiones como cuantos `WHERE` tiene, etc). La *optimización*  depende de muchas otras cosas más serias: cómo tienes diseñado el modelo de datos, cómo se relacionan las tablas, si cada tabla tiene los índices correctos, si las restricciones están bien aplicadas, etc, etc, etc. La consulta es lo de menos. Lo que si te aconsejo, dado que dices cosas como estas: *No sé si tal vez lo ideal sería ejecutar una consulta previa sobre el campo Provincia y ejecutar...* es que

Comment: ...  no subestimes la pontencialidad de los manejadores de bases de datos. Si las tablas están optimizadas puedes escribir una sola consulta sin necesidad de consultas previas y cosas de ese tipo. Si vieras ciertas consultas enormes, larguísimas, con `JOIN` en una enorme cantidad de tablas y que funcionan rapidísimo consultando tablas con millones de registros comprenderías que los DBMS están diseñados para eso. Cuando tú piensas en hacer un trabajo previo para aligerar el trabajo del manejador, estás subestimando su capacidad. Si la consulta es lenta casi siempre es un problema de diseño.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentarios. Edito la entrada para añadir alguna información adicional. Básicamente se trata de una base de datos con los registros del Catastro de España. El objetivo que persigo es buscar inmuebles que cumplan unas determinadas condiciones y se encuentren en una determinada zona. Se trata de una aplicación en Python y a grandes rasgos, quiero efectuar una consulta SQL que me devuelva un dataset que almacenaré en un DataFrame de pandas para hacer diversas operaciones después. Un saludo.

Comment: Ahora que has aportado el código, podemos ver que, aunque sea una única tabla, no has definido índices que agilicen las búsquedas. Para completar la pregunta sólo tienes que poner la consulta que has intentado hacer y te tarda x segundos y ya podremos responderte con propuestas de mejora. Bienvenido a SO.

Comment: Es que ya empezamos mal. ¿Piensas introducir en cada registro una y otra vez el nombre de la provincia? Deberías tener una tabla `provincia` donde cada una existiría de manera única y usar el `IDPROVINCIA` para las relaciones. Si latitud y longitud son las corrdenadas de la provincia es evidente que deberían estar en esa tabla. ¿Por qué usas el tipo de dato `TEXT` para campos que no son tan grandes?

Comment: Recomendacion, Te estas preocupando por algo que te queda grande, demasiado. Antes de preocuparte por esto, deberias ver el tema indices, normalizacion, y realmente entender como funciona una base de datos. Lo que estas preguntando demuestra un poco que no conoces como funciona teoricamente una base de datos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por las respuestas. Los campos de coordenadas son propios de cada Referencia, no de cada provincia por lo que deberán ir necesariamente en la tabla de los registros. Es verdad que podría crear una tabla auxiliar provincia y meter un id. Por otro lado, quisiera preguntar cual sería el campo más adecuado para asignar el índice, teniendo en cuenta que el campo Referencia no está ordenado y que pueden existir duplicados (pueden existir dos inmuebles con la misma referencia), pero no voy a filtrar por este campo.

Comment: Los índices a seleccionar dependen de las búsquedas que vayas a realizar y de las restricciones que necesites definir; pero no te agobies con eso. Necesitamos que concretes tu pregunta: dinos qué quieres obtener, cómo has intentado obtenerlo, el resultado que esperabas a partir de los datos de muestra que nos das y ya te decimos si puedes optimizar algo. Y sí, es bueno estudiar sobre bases de datos, pero lleva mucho tiempo aprenderlo y no te lo vamos a poder enseñar en una única pregunta. Ánimo, que casi lo tienes.

Comment: El diseño de tablas e índices depende del manejador de base de datos que estés utilizando ya que varían las opciones disponibles. Eso es parte del diseño físico de la BD que viene después del diseño lógico.

Answer (score 0):

Para grandes tablas puedes crear un índice agrupado sobre la clave principal que normalmente suele ser un autonumérico identity correlado.

En convivencia con este índice puedes crear otros índices no agrupados sobre las columnas que contienen los valores de las tablas auxiliares: latitud, longitud.

El porqué hacerlo así te lo dejo (https://www.sqlshack.com/es/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-indices-agrupados-y-no-agrupados-en-sql-server/) aquí para que te lo leas antes de dormir

Esta podría ser la lógica inicial suficiente que satisfaga tu problema.

Comment: Poca información con respecto a lo que consulta el usuario, creo yo. Está bien decirle que debe crear indices, pero dile que relación tiene el crear un indice con optimizar la consulta. Hay comentarios mas largos que tu respuesta y que responden mejor a la pregunta. Edita o borra para que se asemeje a lo que se suele considerar una respuesta válida. Un saludo.